# subtracting value from 2 different table then insert the result to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

(question updated)
still new to php.

i have here table 'users' (sorry i've changed some column names)

```
| idn | name | balance | 
  12    matt     500
```

and table 'transactions'

```
| id | store_id | balance | 
  12      1          100
  12      1           50
  12      1           50
```

and so far this is what i've done(not working)

```
 <?php 
 $page_title = 'Student Transaction Log';
 include ('includes/header.html');

 echo "<br><h2>Welcome {$_COOKIE['first_name']}</h2>";

 require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

 $q = "SELECT s.idn, s.balance - 
  COALESCE(
  SELECT SUM(t.balance) FROM transactions t 
  WHERE t.id = s.idn AND t.store_id = 1)
  ,0)
  AS result FROM users s
  WHERE s.idn = {$_COOKIE['idno']} ";   
  $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
  echo '
  <p>Balance: ' . $row['result'] . ' </p>'; 
   }
   mysqli_close($dbc);

   ?>
```

how can i or what should i do to subtract 'result' from the 'balance'(users) and to insert there result together with the student_id
to this table 'result' (well i have not yet included insert statement in my code)

table 'result'

```
| student_id | new balance |
```

thanks guys for the help last time but still my code is not working. so i decided to post my entire code.
whats wrong with my code?
thanks so much

Comment: You have tagged it as php, but i don't get the php part of this. Do you want to do it in one single query or first get the value from the one you showed, do the substraction on php and then do the insert?

Comment: sorry for unclear question. hmm to get first the value of sum(balance2) then subtract it from balance1

Comment: I've updated my solution (fix the external table)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO result
SELECT s.student_id, s.balance_1 - 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT SUM(t.balance2) FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.student_id = s.student_id
        AND t.store_id = 1)
   ,0)
FROM users s
WHERE s.student_id = 12
```

In this way if you have not rows in transactions table you'll have only balance_1

Comment: i replaced "FROM students s" with "FROM users s".
sorry, i dont know what to do next after the select statement. im new to this. 
how can i do the subtract? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this mate:

```
DELIMITER //  
START TRANSACTION;
  SET @balance1 = 0, @bal_total = 0, @student_id = <insert_studentID_here>,  
    @store_id = <insert_storeID_here>;  

  SELECT SUM(balance) INTO @bal_total FROM transactions  
  WHERE student_id = @studentID AND store_id = @storeID;  

  SELECT balance INTO @balance FROM users  
  WHERE student_id = @studentID;  

  INSERT INTO result (student_id, balance)  
  VALUES (@student_id, @balance1 - @bal_total);
COMMIT;  
DELIMITER ;
```

Using the MySQL Transaction will make the process satisfy the 'A' in the ACID structure.
*Link*: [*MySQL Documentation - ACID*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html)

The 'A' means Atomicity, and by using a Transaction you'll make it **run successfully** or **rollback** and make no changes.

You can also convert this Transaction query into a php one by using this: [*PHP Transaction*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

Also, the @variable_name is a session variable. I've put something to handle clearing the value incase you'll be using the query **several** times.

Hope this can help you